# Code signing error when archive with release setting, not with debug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I get the following error when I want to archive my app:

**CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.3'**

If I edit scheme and set it to Debug it works. But I cannot send the archive to apple the organizer gives the following error then:

**No suitable application records were found.
Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect.**

Which is strange because my bundle id is the same as the last part of the identifier in Xcode...

Does anyone know where I have to look for?

Thnx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a Code Signing profile selected for your Target as well.

[image]

Comment: Nice! This fixed the code signing error, but the error which the organizer is giving still appears. This one "No suitable application records were found. Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application on iTunes Connect." hich is strange because my bundle id is the same as the last part of the identifier in Xcode...

Comment: same in iTunes Connect as well?

Comment: Found it! I thought I only needed to enter the suffix, but needed to enter the whole ID. After that it worked! Thxn

Answer (score 0):

Same error message from XCode 4 for me, but solution was to go into iTunesConnect, click on the app in the "Manage my apps" section, click "View details" and then "Ready for Upload" (or somesuch... can't see it anymore).

This seems to shunt the app along a step in the appstore, which then makes it possible to validate and (I hope) submit the app from XCode.

Horrible process.  Two apps in the store, up to my third, and still find this process confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Both set the Code Signing in the (project->Bulding Settings) and (Targets->Building Settings).
It work well for me in the Xcode 4.3.1 ,Hope it's usefull for you.